# Can only retrieve all Services when trying to get Paired Bluetooth Devices

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, rfcomm

I am writing a Windows/Windows Phone 8.1 Bluetooth App with SPP where the end user needs to select the paired Bluetooth device to use.

**Problem #1:**

I am having trouble trying to get just the paired Bluetooth devices that are paired to my device. I can only get ***all*** services on the device.

Note: I am using a Windows Phone 8.1 device Bluetooth Paired to a Windows 7 Laptop

```
DeviceInformationCollection CollectionOfDeviceInfo;

PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paried"] = ""; 

//CollectionOfDeviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort)); 
CollectionOfDeviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
```

The FindAllAsync() gives me all the services on the phone, including the paired Bluetooth and all those services.

**Problem #2:**

I don't know which service I need from the Bluetooth for SPP. If I knew which service I needed from the Bluetooth I would filter for that from the giant list of services.

I have been looking at
[BluetoothRfcommChat](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Rfcomm-Chat-afcee559) and
[BluetoothCommunicationSample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-communication-7130c260) from MSDN, but it is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, I got RfcommServiceId.SerialPort to work. Needed to add

```
<Capabilities>
  <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
    <m2:Device Id="any">
      <m2:Function Type="name.serialPort"/>
    </m2:Device>
  </m2:DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

to my Package.appxmanifest (hint: Right click->View Code)

Then my line

```
CollectionOfDeviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

worked great.

To solve this I got the [BluetoothRfcommChat](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Rfcomm-Chat-afcee559) to work on a Windows 8.1 laptop and on my Winows Phone 8.1 device. I did need to restart the laptop after pairing and run the app from the startup tile and not from debugging. The phone side I didn't need to restart and can run from debugging.

Comment: There's a typo, it should be name:serialPort, not with a point. You may also add this link for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth